# Math expression to java method?

Tags: java, math, methods, trigonometry

I have a math expression that I need to express as a Java code with the end result in degrees. I'm doing something wrong because the result should be -4.812 according to the calculator but I'm getting 0.849 when compiling the code. I would appreciate any help.

[image]

Below are some snippets of my code:

```
public E6B()
{
    d = 340;
    w = 255;
    va = 95;
    vw = 8;
}

public double windCorAng()
{
    double test1 = Math.toDegrees(Math.asin ( vw * Math.sin(w-d)/va)); 
    return test1; 
}
```

Comment: I would recommend using floating point precision variables throughout your calculation.  It looks to me like you're mixing integers with doubles; don't do that (in general).

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I'm using double throughout my code...

Comment: [https://www.google.com/search?q=arcsin%288*sin%28255-340%29%2F95%29+to+degree](https://www.google.com/search?q=arcsin%288*sin%28255-340%29%2F95%29+to+degree) => 0.849579755 degree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [`Math.sin`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#sin-double-)'s documentation, its argument should be given in radians, no degrees. You can use [`Math.toRandians`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#toRadians-double-) to convert those degrees to Randians:

```
double test1 = Math.toDegrees(Math.asin ( vw * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(w-d))/va)); 
// Here ------------------------------------------------^
```

Answer (score 0):

You correctly noted that `asin` returns an angle in radians, so you added `Math.toDegrees`. However, `sin` accepts an angle in radians as well! What you are passing now (`w - d`) seems to be an angle in degrees. You need to convert that to radians:

```
double test1 = Math.toDegrees(Math.asin ( vw * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(w-d))/va));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I get it!